# Access Kotlin Interface/Class property by string key?

Tags: java, kotlin, reflection

I need to access a class instance property similar to accessing a map in Kotlin.

For a map it goes like this

```
val myMap: Map<String, String> = mapOf("foo" to "bar")
assertThat(myMap["foo"]).isEqualTo("bar"
```

Now I want something similar to a class

```
data class House(
  val street: String
)

// pseudo code wish
fun foo() {
  val valueOfFoo: String = House::class.members["foo"].callGet()
}
```

I read into reflection but can't find a way to call it. I know the problem somewhat is that there is no class instance passed or specified. However I wonder if there is such thing?

```
val house = House("Baker Street 5")
val valueOfFoo: String = House::class.members["foo"].callGetWithInstance(house)
   
assertThat(valueOfFoo).isEqualTo("Baker Street 5")
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with this? Mixing up object properties and map entries is a common pattern in some loosely-typed, dynamic languages — but in Kotlin there are usually better approaches. Reflection is powerful but slow, ugly, fragile, insecure, hard to read, and turns compile-time errors into run-time ones; it's needed for frameworks, libraries, plug-ins, and compile-time tools, but for general application programming there's usually a better way.

Comment: I am writing a script language. When transpiling to Kotlin logic I have very large if-clauses that I'd like to shrink using this method by accessing fields by string. This might impact performance which is ok in my use-case

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sure.  `declaredMemberProperties` gives you a collection of `KProperty1`, which has a [`get`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.reflect/-k-property1/get.html) method.

Just write something like

```
House::class.declaredMemberProperties.find { it.name == "street" }!!.get(house)
```